# Can I cast guidance immediately before a check and keep Hex active?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

I am currently playing a Warlock and I am going to take the tome pact boon. I know you cannot be concentrating on two spells at once but if I am concentrating on Hex and I cast guidance immediately before an ability check (same round) would Hex end? It is six seconds or less that guidance would be up. Is that enough time for Hex to end? Could it be considered instantaneous in this case? I guess my main question is could I cast guidance immediately before a check and keep Hex active?

Comment: For any down votes I would appreciate a reason. Thank you.

Comment: [We don't require comments for downvotes](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-we-require-comments-on-downvotes) for a good reason, its part of how the site works. Though I suspect if this does attract downvotes it will be due to a lack of research effort, the rules are fairly clear on this.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this plan, since Guidance takes an Action to cast, and most ability checks require an action (though not all). It might make the question clearer if you clarified how you intended to do an ability check in the same round you had already used your action (although the answer would be the same).

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Guidance is used for others to use it. I wouldn't be doing the ability check myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Hex would drop if you cast Guidance

Guidance and Hex are both concentration spells. The rules on concentration state:

> #### Casting another spell that requires concentration
>
> You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

There is no time limitation on this, even if it only lasts one turn you can't have concentration on both spells and hex will drop.